# When exporting, mask behind text becomes garbled (Data Driven Pages)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pdf, data-driven-pages, png, arcgis-10.6

I am using Data Driven Pages with different rotations for a project. When I export to PDF or PNG, the mask behind the text moves and rotates. It does not seem to rotate in the direction of the data frame. We have tried MXD Dr, Repair Geometry tool, and re-creating the MXD. I am able to export fine until I insert the data driven page index. We also created a new data driven page index.shp and had the same problem.

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

9/25: Tried exporting again; masks w label engine (in red) did not show up, Fischer Rd (annotation) is still rotated/ wonky.
[image]

Comment: Is the text driven by a labelling engine or is it an annotation element?

Comment: Its a combination of both. The labels in the image are labeled with the Standard Label Engine, but my roads are annotation and are also affected.